# How to individually find the state of a component of an instantiated object within a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have a list of moving enemies, and while I was able to make them hold individual HP points that react correctly with bullet damage, I wanted to have the instantiated object stop its movement when reaching 0 HP - but I only manage to have all of the listed objects stop.

The HP is stored in a simple class called EnemyHP that only holds the public integer.

Here is part of the EnemyController class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform enemyHolder;
    public float speed;
    public GameObject shot;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public GameObject enemy2;
    public Text winText;
    int secCount;
    float timer = 0;
    public float fireRate = 0.997f;
    public int enemyCount;

    void Start()
    {
        enemyCount = 0;
        secCount = 0;
        enemyHolder = GetComponent<Transform>();
        winText.enabled = false;
        InvokeRepeating("MoveEnemy", 0f, 0.016f);
    }
    private List<GameObject> allSpawns = new List<GameObject>();

    void MoveEnemy()
    {
        float xPosition = Random.Range(-11f, 11f);
        int enemyType = Random.Range(0, 8);
        secCount = Random.Range(2, 4);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer >= secCount && enemyCount < 25)
        {
            if (enemyType > 0)
            {
                GameObject spawned = Instantiate(enemy, new Vector3(xPosition, 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                allSpawns.Add(spawned);
            }
            else
            {
                GameObject spawned = Instantiate(enemy2, new Vector3(xPosition, 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                allSpawns.Add(spawned);
            }
            enemyCount++;
            timer = timer - secCount;
        }
        foreach (GameObject thisEnemy in allSpawns)
        {
          //I expected this part to work
            EnemyHP hpComponent = thisEnemy.GetComponent<EnemyHP>();
            if (hpComponent.health > 0)
            {
                if (thisEnemy != null)
                {
                    thisEnemy.transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1 * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
                }
            }
        } ...
```

Here is the bullet controller that affects individual HP correctly:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform bullet;
    public int power;
    public float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bullet = GetComponent<Transform>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bullet.position += transform.up * speed;
        if (bullet.position.y >= 10)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag ("Enemy") || other.CompareTag("Enemy2"))
        {
            EnemyHP hpComponent = other.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHP>();
            hpComponent.health = hpComponent.health - power;
            Destroy(gameObject);
            if (hpComponent.health < 1)
            {
                hpComponent.health = 0;

                Destroy(other.gameObject, 1);
                PlayerScore.playerScore++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the EnemyHP class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHP : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Had you considered to have the Health or Enemy class handle its own movement and stop-on-health logic? Right now, you have an overarching allSpawns list -- how do you remove hit objects from it, by the way? -- but you could composit your structure in a way that the objects are more self-maintaining. Short of that, I would suggest you add debugging into what the health value is for particular enemies, and where it might get set to 0 accidentally (though your code seems fine in that regard), and also check if you get any errors that might stop the movement loop -- e.g. an undefined object.

Comment: On a sidenote, in the future when you iterate over a specific component during every or nearly every frame, consider first storing the components itself into a list like `List<EnemyHP>` or `EnemyHP[]` instead of using `GetComponent` on all the individual gameObjects all the time, which may introduce lag.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I'm having the enemy object removed by the collision detection running a check on what object it has just hit, and then performing actions with `other.` . The issue with with having health in the Enemy class is that the Enemy class is applied to an empty EnemyHolder object. The prefab enemies are instantiated under the holder object, and the health class is applied to the prefab enemies. There ARE many health as it is reduced on an individual basis when hit by the bullet object, but I don't know why after it checks once for _any_ instantiation reaching 0 health it stops all.

Comment: I know you are destroying the object (after 1 second), but that doesn't mean it gets removed from the `allSpawns` -- it would still be in that list as `null` and return an error if you get its `hpComponent` and try receive a `health` value from it. Either way, that would all be fixed if you let the functionality be self-maintained by the Enemy/ HP components (as there would be no external redundant references into the objects to begin with).

Comment: Whoops, the solution was really easy! Your explanation helped me see the issue. I needed to have it check for !=null first and only then pull the (EnemyHP) hpComponent.health int from thisEnemy and check its value.

Comment: Great. Also, make sure you check your error log in the future. This error would have been printed out there in red. And don't forget to clean your Enemy `allSpawns` list every now and then, otherwise it would grow endlessly over time.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen Yes, this is what I wanted to know. If it retains "null" places in the list it probably takes up more and more enemy. Is there any way I need to manually tell it to remove the null places?